# Random sampling using Metropolis vs. Accept-Reject

Tags: statistics, matlab, monte-carlo

I'm working on a project comparing the accept-reject (von Neumann) and Metropolis methods of sampling. I'm generating a sample of size $N$ from a normal distribution $N(1,(\frac{1}{2})^2)$. What I found was that for the Accept-Reject method, the algorithm is much slower, but gives very good results even for relatively small $N$. On the other hand, the Metropolis algorithm I'm using works much quicker, but even for very big $N$ (for example $10^5$), it gives a worse result.

Are my results correct? Is this the main difference between the two algorithms?

This is the MATLAB code I'm using for the Metropolis algorithm:

```
function [X, total] = metropolis(f,N,b) %METROPOLIS Generate pseudorandom numbers using Metropolis algorithm. %   f - pdf to be simulated %   M - upper bound on pdf %   N - size of generated sample %   b - interval from which to sample

    dx = diff(b)/100;
    total = 0;
    n = 1;
    X = zeros(N,1);
    X(1)=0.5*(max(b)+min(b));

    while n < N

    total = total + 1;
    xt = X(n)-dx + rand(1)*2*dx;

    if f(xt) >= f(X(n))
        X(n+1) = xt;
        n = n+1;
    else
        r = rand(1);
        if r < f(xt)/f(X(n))
            X(n+1) = xt;
            n = n+1;
        else
            X(n+1) = X(n);
            n = n+1;
        end

    end
     end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance of the Metropolis method depends heavily on the class of trial Metropolis steps considered. (In this 1-D case, on the step size among which you choose your trial step.) If the step size is very large, the Metropolis method behaves like the accept-reject method.

If the step size is too small, then you run into the problem of long correlation lengths.  That is, although you are getting (say) $10^5^ samples, if the correlation length is 10,000 steps, your effective sample size is only 10 points. Then your statistical sample will likely "give a bad result."

The Metropolis method shines in situations where the space of possible points is high-dimensioned and you can't analytically place a tight limit on your sample space, so that the accept/reject method very rarely gives an accept.  Here, the accept /reject method might take way too long to provide a statistically significant set of sample points.

In that case, if there is a natural and computationally efficient way to calculate the probability difference for a step which is large in a local sense, yet small in the overall probability sense, then Metropolis is very useful.  For example, in lattice gauge theory, the change in action associated with a change in a single link on the lattice is small enough that the acceptance rate is fairly high.  And even though the correlation "time" may be thousands of steps, this is a much more efficient way to generate an ensemble of (farily) decorrelated samples than accept/reject would be.

Comment: I have added the MATLAB code for my Metropolis algorithm. The step is 1/100 of the interval, which I chose to be $[-10\sigma,10\sigma]$ = $[-5,5]$.

Comment: Yes, I see you are putting into $X$ every accepted Metropolis step.  The correlation time in your case is something like 80 steps, so to get two points that are decorrelated at the level of a part per thousand you would need to insert every 25-th accepted step into $X$.

Comment: And of course if you do that, the accept/reject method will be much more efficient.

Comment: So...what should I set $dx$ to? How do I make my Metropolis work better?